# Can not get data of previous 2 days from Youtube Reporting API

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

Today is 19th May, I can get data before 16th but nothing for 17th and 18th from youtube analytics API, is there something wrong?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query?apix_params=%7B%22dimensions%22%3A%22day%22%2C%22endDate%22%3A%222020-05-17%22%2C%22ids%22%3A%22channel%3D%3DMINE%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22metrics%22%3A%22views%22%2C%22startDate%22%3A%222020-05-17%22%7D